Atmospheric Improvement: Increased greenhouse gasses vs. increased pressure
In my scenario I am imagining a terraforming process, performed by a human-like civilization. The world that they chose to settle only receives roughly 20% of the sunlight compared to earth, due to it being 2.6 AU away from its host star.
Anyway they decided to first modify the atmosphere. Their initial goal is to increase the average temperature from -80°C to more earth-like 15°C.
They now have a few possibilities to achieve this:

Increase Carbon Dioxide level. According to my calculations and research, they would need to raise the CO2 level to 6% of the atmosphere, if density and pressure are to remain the same. However, the atmosphere then may be toxic for humans if they breathe the air without some kind of filters, masks and oxygen tanks. I'm assuming similar effects if other greenhouse gasses such as methane would be increased accordingly to achieve a similar warming effect.

Increase atmospheric density and surface pressure. This means that all components of Earth's atmosphere would have to be added, especially nitrogen and oxygen. This would result in a greenhouse effect without over-representing any single element.

Add Methane. Since it is a much stronger greenhouse gas, a way smaller concentration will be required to achieve the required effect. I am estimating out of the blue: 0.2% of methane will be found in the atmosphere once the terraforming process is finished. Generally the exposure to this amount is not considered toxic to humans. Increased flammability could be an issue though.

Add water Vapor Avoiding the fire hazard problem, its also completely non toxic. But it could cause some nasty storms. Also high humidity could cause a variety of health problems.


Which solution would provide the best (or least bad) and more long term result for human habitability? I'm suspecting that increased density will have unexpected consequences for human health, too.

There are two main methods using greenhouse gases that you can use to make this planet habitable, and one is potentially naturally-occurring.
The two options: volcanic Hydrogen and fluorinated gases.
Option 1: Volcanic Hydrogen 
(See this)
For a planet receiving 20% the insolation Earth gets, an atmosphere with approximately 30% Hydrogen (in an otherwise Nitrogen atmosphere) could maintain temperatures similar to Earth.
Hydrogen is, of course, a light gas that escapes very easily, but a planet with different internal chemistry (such as one closer to that of early Earth) might be able to produce (and maintain) volcanic Hydrogen and could reasonably reach Hydrogen levels with a sufficiently high greenhouse effect.
If you go with this option, do note that it will be difficult to also have breathable levels of Oxygen in this atmosphere (because they tend to react to form water), so you will also need a much higher air pressure in order to have a partial pressure of Oxygen that is breathable. See the gas mixture hydrox for breathable (and unreactive) Hydrogen/Oxygen ratios.
Option 2: Fluorinated gases
(See here)
Fluorinated gases such as Sulphur Hexafluoride are the most powerful greenhouse gases you can use (23,900 times that of Carbon Dioxide). Sulphur Hexafluoride is also relatively harmless in small concentrations (in terms of breathing), stable and long-lasting. These are heavy gases though, and will tend to accumulate in the lowlands of your planet.
A terraforming civilisation could potentially use this gas to keep outer planets warm for a very long period of time, as long as they have enough fluorine (which is a relatively rare element) to make the gases.

Thank you so much. You helped my out a lot :)

@Ben No problem :) . By the way, if you are terraforming planets with low insolation, their climate will be more homogenous the less insolation they receive, assuming they don’t receive other significant heating factors like tidal-heating. Winds will be slower and humidity will be higher, saturating the air with moisture. This effect is even worse on smaller and lower gravity worlds. The terraforming wiki I linked discusses that in more detail.

Increasing CO2 level in atmosphere is very good starting point for terraforming process. I don't know about 6%, but high CO2 level makes it much easier on plants to grow - they will grow faster, bigger and stronger, needing less water - but then again - high level is 0.1% If CO2 hits 1% of atmospheric composition it is an equivalent to fumigation in modern-day greenhouses. Increasing CO2 in a greenhouse to 1% content for an hour or two doesn't harm the plants much, but it kills all pests... Much better than chemical spraying.
I'd say you're starting from the wrong place. Since the temperature and sunlight levels are a serious problem, I would concentrate on increasing those in the first place, rather than manipulating atmosphere.
I would implement sunlight harvesting program. Mirror arrays scattered in the inner system, closer to the sun, could be a fast and easy method.
To at least double the sunlight delivered to the surface, 45 petawatts would have to be gathered in-system and re-focused on the planet. Sounds big, but I guess civilization attempting terraform a barely habitable planet should have tech level to do that no problem.
Add 90 petawatts to the natural sunlight and you're at 75% of Earth. More than sufficient for other steps to commence.
We actually are at that level, we just have no space-presence to do that on the industrial scale.

Frame challenge: both approaches are unlikely to keep a breathable atmosphere for humans.
We have evolved to breathe in an atmosphere with a rather stable composition, and changing that without affecting us is difficult.
As you correctly point out, option 1 has too much CO2 to be breathable. But also option 2 has its own shortcoming: when it comes to Oxygen, a too high partial pressure will result in Oxygen toxicity, and the partial pressure doesn't care of what other gasses are present to dilute the Oxygen.

Pulmonary toxicity occurs only with exposure to partial pressures of oxygen greater than 0.5 bar

This means that if you go for option 2 you are limited to increasing pressure by a factor 2.5 before bordering the toxicity region.
I think you are left with the third option of adding a very strong greenhouse gas.
